# getting to an ELF file information

Tags: linux, unix, elf

ok...
so im suppose to write a program that prints all of the sections name in an elf file using only mmap (thats not important...)

so what i did so far is this - 
maped the file into the stat structure = 
map_start = mmap(0, fd_stat.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) <0 )

casted it into the write format from the starting point i got = 
header = (Elf32_Ehdr *) map_start;

gotten the section header offset from the file = 
secoff = header->e_shoff;

now - i know i need to go to the map_start+secoff location - that will give me the section table, and the sh_name will give me an index for the string table...

how to i go to the sting table?
how is it represented?
how do i use it? and is the value in sh_name the index in the string table (if it is represented as an array) , or an offset..

anyway - lets say i want to print the first two section's name - how do i do it givven the code i wrote above 
help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting the sh_name member in a section header elf file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863510/getting-the-sh-name-member-in-a-section-header-elf-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
header = (Elf32_Ehdr *) map_start;
secoff = header->e_shoff;
```

This is probably wrong. Unless the Elf32_Ehdr structure is explicitly declared `__attribute__((packed))`, the compiler will eventually insert padding between the members of the structure, so `sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr) != (the actual size of an ELF header section)`. Why not simply use the libelf accessor functions instead?

**Update:** if you're not allowed to use accessor functions, you'll have to do something like this:

```
Elf32_Ehdr hdr;
memcpy(&hdr.e_ident, map_start + 0, EI_NIDENT);
memcpy(&hdr.e.type, map_start + 0 + sizeof(Elf32_half), sizeof(Elf32_Half));
```

et cetera.

Comment: well, this task was givven to us so we'll understand the structure of an ELF file - we are suppose to get the names using the data we get directly from the elf header... i suppose they dont want us to use the accessor functions.. i didnt even know there are accessor functions...  when i write the code i do get the offset , and the compiler does allow me to go to the elf header using the casting above - so i dont really know if its wrong or not... its working.. i think

Comment: But it is NOT working since you don't get the expected results. You want to fill up the structure's members one-by-one, coding the appropriate offsets and lengths by hand, and them memcpy()'ing them.

Comment: well... i actually didnt understand what you are sayinng - its the first time im using the ELF files.  just to be sure you understand what im trying to do (you probably do... but then i really dont have anything to say because i dont know enought)

Comment: well, i i just want to print the name of the sections..i didnt really understood what you did there - thaks for the time by the way..!