# How do I extract all the fields from a Section Header for an elf file?

Tags: c++, elf, readelf

So I was able to get the sh_name using the Elf tutorial here: http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF_Tutorial and this question: [getting the sh_name member in a section header elf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863510/getting-the-sh-name-member-in-a-section-header-elf-file), but when using the same method to get the rest of the fields in the section header, I don't get the same output as I do when I call `readelf -S` on the object file I'm analyzing. I'm printing out a casted string of the following:

```
sh_strtab_p + shdr[i].sh_offset
```

and I'm getting nothing when I do. Is it an issue of casting? Am I supposed to be casting it as an int instead or something similar? I thought it was going to be a string format since I assumed `sh_strtab` was  the associated string table to the section header.

Comment: is your input stream reading in binary mode?

Comment: Nope, that might be why. Should it still be empty on return though?

Comment: Hmm, it didn't seem to make a difference? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out I'm being silly, and the answer is just to convert the `Elf_Shdr.sh_offset` (which is a uint32_t) to hex, and you'll get the same value as when you use `readelf`. There is no need to use a string index for anything besides name. All the other fields can be processed the same way, and if you want the string representation of the flags and type, there's a table here mapping the value to the name of the flag/type: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3677/chapter6-94076/index.html.