# ELF - what's the purpose o the sh_offset field?

Tags: elf

I'm trying to learn more about the ELF format, particularly, section headers and I just [came across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863510/getting-the-sh-name-member-in-a-section-header-elf-file) the following:

```
Elf32_Ehdr *ehdr = (Elf32_Ehdr*)p;
Elf32_Shdr *shdr = (Elf32_Shdr *)(p + ehdr->e_shoff);
int shnum = ehdr->e_shnum;

Elf32_Shdr *sh_strtab = &shdr[ehdr->e_shstrndx];
const char *const sh_strtab_p = p + sh_strtab->sh_offset;

for (int i = 0; i < shnum; ++i) {
   printf("%2d: %4d '%s'\n", i, shdr[i].sh_name,
          sh_strtab_p + shdr[i].sh_name);
}

 return 0;
}
```

Now, I understand that this is basically iterating through the section table and printing the section names but I'm still confused about the *sh_offset* field. What exactly does it do? If *e_shstrndx* is already pointing to the string table section why do we need *sh_offset*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If e_shstrndx is already pointing to the string table section why do we need sh_offset

The `e_shstrndx` is an index into *section table*; it tells you which section describes (contains) the string table.

But it *doesn't* tell you where the *data* (the strings themselves) resides. You need `sh_offset` for that.

Here is a [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#/media/File:Elf-layout--en.svg). `.e_shoff` tells you where the table of sections starts, `.e_shstrndx` tells you which element of that table is the one you want, and *that element's* `.sh_offset` tells you where in the file `.shstrtab` section's *data* is (i.e. where the strings themselves are).