# Print an elf32_Word as a word

Tags: c, printf, elf

I am working with ELF files.
I have a variables of type `elf32_Word` and I would like to print them in the terminal as text.

For example, my section table name:

```
Elf32_Shdr ST;
printf("%d",ST[].sh_name);
```

but the `"%d"` value doesn't make it (it is print as an integer).

FYI, i know the elf32 declaration in `elf.h`:

```
typedef __u32   Elf32_Word;
```

Sections with well printed names :

```
index    value      size      type bind oth ver shndx          name
  [0]  0x00000000 0x00000000  NOTY LOCL  D    0 UNDEF          
  [1]  0x00025c0c 0x00000000  FUNC GLOB  D    2 UNDEF          .udiv
  [2]  0x00025e00 0x00000140  OBJT WEAK  D    1 .bss           _iob
```

Comment: `doen't make it` - what does it mean if a value "does not make it"?

Comment: It print a number, and i want a name

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865542/3436922)

Comment: Yes it is perfect, thanks. Then my thread is a doublon, i will delete

Comment: Leave it.It will be closed as a duplicate and will help someone else to find the solution in future